# I want to display the text on clicking on the input

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay so I am trying display the text on focus in the input field all i've done so far is this.

**HTML**

```
<form>
                <span id="name">
                Name : <input type="text" class="name" name="name" title="lust"/><br />
                <span>ENTER NAME</span>
                </span>
                <span id="mail">
                E-mail : <input type="text" class="mail" name="mail" /><br />
                <span>ENTER NAME</span>
                </span>
                <input type="submit" class="button" />
            </form>
```

**CSS**

```
#forms {
    position: relative;
}

#name span, #mail span {
    display: none;
}

input[type='text']{
    border: 1px solid #008008;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type='text']:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #008080;
}

.assistant {
    position: abosolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Can anyone help me achieve this am I doing wrong or I am in correct path?
I will be greatful if someone actually help me out.

Like the tooltip on clicking the input field I mean.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please clarify?

Comment: Search for "new fiddle", paste in your HTML/CSS code, click on Tidy Up and then fix your HTML (several non matching tags).  After that, save your fiddle (makes a permalink) and then update your question with the fiddle link.  This shouldn't take you long but you will learn a bit in the process and also make it easier for the community to give you help with your specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for you I will suggest [jQuery.tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)! Also I will say you need to change your markup. Try this, and let me know if it works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label input').tipsy({
        gravity: 'w',
        trigger: 'focus'
    });
});
```

```css
html, body, body * {
 font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}

/* -- forms -- */
#forms {
 position: relative;
}

#name span, #mail span {
 display: none;
}

input[type='text']{
 border: 1px solid #008008;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #f1f1f1;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type='text']:focus {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #008080;
}

#name span.assistant, #mail span.assistant {
 position: abosolute;
 top: 0px;
    display: block;
}

form {display: block;}
form ul, form ul li {display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
form ul li strong {display: inline-block; width: 100px; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px;}
form ul li.submit {padding-left: 115px;}
form ul li .button {display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #ccf; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #0ff; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.css" />
<div id="forms">
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li><label><strong>Name:</strong> <input type="text" class="name" name="name" title="Enter Name" /></label></li>
            <li><label><strong>E-mail:</strong> <input type="text" class="mail" name="mail" title="Enter e-Mail" /></label></li>
            <li class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Change the CSS, and note the markup inside the `<form>` tag.

Comment: @NaveenNiraula There's an option called `trigger: 'focus'` in the initialisation, that does the job. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not so clear to understand what you want.
I think you want to show the "ENTER NAME" text on the input boxes when there's no content in there.

If that's case, try using the `placeholder` attribute on the input element.

Comment: I was just needing like a tooltip when I click on the input?

Answer (score 1):

No need for any JavaScript, this can be achieved with CSS alone. You need to use the negation pseudo class [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and the adjacent sibling selector [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to hide the `span` when the `input` is not focussed, like so:

```
input[type=text]:not(:focus)+span{
    display:none;
}
```